# Using a class that is used by many different classes. But if changed from one, all must change

Tags: c#

I have a class

```
public class Camera()
{
    int w;
    int h;
    public int x;
    public int y;

    ...
}
```

I use it in many different classes, like Player, Drawbox, Object etc. It is mostly inherited through constructor. Everything works, yet I was wondering if there were a more decent way to do it, like a global class or something like that.

Comment: Do you mean you only ever want a single camera instance, or something else?

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking

Comment: "But if changed from one, all must change"  this bit sounds like you need a static class

Comment: Are you talking about using an #include directive to load the same class declaration in multiple other files?

Comment: There is no #include directive in C#.

Comment: Actually I wanted a single instance of a class throughout all project. The static worked perfectly. Sorry for an unclear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make it a ***Static*** Class then it is access from all the other class
in your project and i think more reasonable for your project

Comment: Thank you, I'm still quite new at this. Still thinking how realization of calling it will be. Gonna go read more about static classes.

Comment: Instead of using static methods, you may consider using a `singleton` instance instead (I can't believe I am actually advising using a `singleton` though, goes to show that a static class is probably even worse)